# Error:: AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudsearch

I am using Command Line Tool for uploading files from Amazon S3 to CloudSearch for Indexing using the command-

```
cs-import-documents -d searchdev3 --source s3://mybucket/html
```

It is giving error-

> Connecting to CloudSearch in region [us-east-1]
>
> AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header (Service: Amazon S
>   3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 506FD29F73XXXXXX)

How can I track where the problem is occurring?

**UPDATE**

When run with `--verbose` I received below output-

```
Looking up DocServiceEndpoint for domain searchdev3 using config service at null

Connecting to CloudSearch in region [us-east-1]
Sending to endpoint [https://cloudsearch.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/] for region [u
s-east-1]
Connection request: [route: {s}->https://cloudsearch.us-east-1.amazonaws.com][to
tal kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 50; total allocated: 0 of 50]
Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://cloudsearch.us-east-1.amazonaws.c
om][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 50; total allocated: 1 of 50]
Connecting to cloudsearch.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443
CookieSpec selected: best-match
Auth cache not set in the context
Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Sending request: POST / HTTP/1.1
>> "POST / HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: cloudsearch.us-east-1.amazonaws.com[\r][\n]"
>> "Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=XXXXXXXX/20151130/us-
east-1/cloudsearch/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;user-agent;x-amz-date, Signa
ture=e93cd0c22189084ff55c1084[\r][\n]"
>> "X-Amz-Date: 20151130T103603Z[\r][\n]"
>> "User-Agent: aws-internal/3[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Length: 73[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> POST / HTTP/1.1
>> Host: cloudsearch.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
>> Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=XXXXXXXX/20151130/us-e
ast-1/cloudsearch/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;user-agent;x-amz-date, Signat
ure=e93cd0c22189084ff55c1084
>> X-Amz-Date: 20151130T103603Z
>> User-Agent: aws-internal/3
>> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
>> Content-Length: 73
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
>> "Action=DescribeDomains&Version=2013-01-01&DomainNames.member.1=searchdev3"
<< "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
<< "x-amzn-RequestId: 2907d340-974e-11e5-a6e5-33953f55803d[\r][\n]"
<< "Content-Type: text/xml[\r][\n]"
<< "Content-Length: 1635[\r][\n]"
<< "Date: Mon, 30 Nov 2015 10:36:05 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<< x-amzn-RequestId: 2907d340-974e-11e5-a6e5-33953f55803d
<< Content-Type: text/xml
<< Content-Length: 1635
<< Date: Mon, 30 Nov 2015 10:36:05 GMT
<< "<"
<< "D"
<< "e"
<< "s"
<< "cribeDomainsResponse xmlns=""
<< "http://cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-01-01/">[\n]"
<< "  <DescribeDomainsResult>[\n]"
<< "    <DomainStatusList>[\n]"
<< "      <member>[\n]"
<< "        <Created>true</Created>[\n]"
<< "        <RequiresIndexDocuments>false</RequiresIndexDocuments>[\n]"
<< "        <SearchInstanceType>search.m1.small</SearchInstanceType>[\n]"
<< "        <DomainId>613875336225/searchdev3</DomainId>[\n]"
<< "        <DocService>[\n]"
<< "          <Endpoint>doc-searchdev3-ytmgti5ijnobqprgg65e4yxrhe.us-east-1.clou
dsearch.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>[\n]"
<< "        </DocService>[\n]"
<< "        <SearchPartitionCount>1</SearchPartitionCount>[\n]"
<< "        <Deleted>false</Deleted>[\n]"
<< "        <SearchService>[\n]"
<< "          <Endpoint>search-searchdev3-ytmgti5ijnobqprgg65e4yxrhe.us-east-1.c
loudsearch.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>[\n]"
<< "        </SearchService>[\n]"
<< "        <DomainName>searchdev3</DomainName>[\n]"
<< "        <Processing>true</Processing>[\n]"
<< "        <SearchInstanceCount>1</SearchInstanceCount>[\n]"
<< "        <ARN>arn:aws:cloudsearch:us-east-1:613875336225:domain/searchdev3</A
RN>[\n]"
<< "        <Limits>[\n]"
<< "          <AvailableInstanceTypes>[\n]"
<< "            <member>search.m1.small</member>[\n]"
<< "            <member>search.m3.medium</member>[\n]"
<< "            <member>search.m3.large</member>[\n]"
<< "            <member>search.m3.xlarge</member>[\n]"
<< "            <member>search.m3.2xlarge</member>[\n]"
<< "          </AvailableInstanceTypes>[\n]"
<< "          <MaximumReplicationCount>5</MaximumReplicationCount>[\n]"
<< "          <MaximumPartitionCount>10</MaximumPartitionCount>[\n]"
<< "        </Limits>[\n]"
<< "      </member>[\n]"
<< "    </DomainStatusList>[\n]"
<< "  </DescribeDomainsResult>[\n]"
<< "  <ResponseMetadata>[\n]"
<< "    <RequestId>2907d340-974e-11e5-a6e5-33953f55803d</RequestId>[\n]"
<< "  </ResponseMetadata>[\n]"
<< "</DescribeDomainsResponse>[\n]"
Connection [id: 0][route: {s}->https://cloudsearch.us-east-1.amazonaws.com] can
be kept alive indefinitely
Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://cloudsearch.us-east-1.amazonaws
.com][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 50; total allocated: 1 of 50]
Creating S3 source reader
Connection request: [route: {s}->https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com][total
 kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 50; total allocated: 0 of 50]
Connection leased: [id: 1][route: {s}->https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com]
[total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 50; total allocated: 1 of 50]
Connecting to mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com:443
CookieSpec selected: best-match
Auth cache not set in the context
Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Sending request: GET /?prefix=html HTTP/1.1
>> "GET /?prefix=html HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com[\r][\n]"
>> "Authorization: AWS XXXXXXXX:eA+KR8i3SpRQdTS/pxeBeci7iOw=[\r][\n]
"
>> "User-Agent: aws-internal/3[\r][\n]"
>> "Date: Mon, 30 Nov 2015 10:36:05 +00:00[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> GET /?prefix=html HTTP/1.1
>> Host: mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com
>> Authorization: AWS XXXXXXXX:eA+KR8i3SpRQdTS/pxeBeci7iOw=
>> User-Agent: aws-internal/3
>> Date: Mon, 30 Nov 2015 10:36:05 +00:00
>> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
<< "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden[\r][\n]"
<< "x-amz-bucket-region: us-east-1[\r][\n]"
<< "x-amz-request-id: DA6567BEA36C46F9[\r][\n]"
<< "x-amz-id-2: kCC6NxI43AJi3G+YB0Dxgoc6ZrCGh/V3Wc4nhSnxk+mxYpdH50am3BBgzXfkLHrj
[\r][\n]"
<< "Content-Type: application/xml[\r][\n]"
<< "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
<< "Date: Mon, 30 Nov 2015 10:36:06 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "Server: AmazonS3[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
<< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
<< x-amz-bucket-region: us-east-1
<< x-amz-request-id: DA6567BEA36C46F9
<< x-amz-id-2: kCC6NxI43AJi3G+YB0Dxgoc6ZrCGh/V3Wc4nhSnxk+mxYpdH50am3BBgzXfkLHrj
<< Content-Type: application/xml
<< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<< Date: Mon, 30 Nov 2015 10:36:06 GMT
<< Server: AmazonS3
<< "117[\r][\n]"
<< "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>[\n]"
<< "<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>AWS authentication requires a valid
 Date or x-amz-date header</Message><RequestId>DA6567BEA36C46F9</RequestId><Host
Id>kCC6NxI43AJi3G+YB0Dxgoc6ZrCGh/V3Wc4nhSnxk+mxYpdH50am3BBgzXfkLHrj</HostId></Er
ror>"
<< "[\r][\n]"
<< "0[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
Connection [id: 1][route: {s}->https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com] can be
kept alive indefinitely
Connection released: [id: 1][route: {s}->https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.co
m][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 50; total allocated: 1 of 50]
AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header (Service: Amazon S
3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: DA6567BEA36C46F9)
Error Type:       Client
Error Code:       AccessDenied
HTTP Code:        403
Request ID:       DA6567BEA36C46F9
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@12a7737
```

Comment: can you run it with `--verbose` to get some additional logging and post the output?

Comment: It's interesting that it's including x-amz-date in the first request (POST /)  but not in the second one (GET /prefix=html). I decompiled the jar to see what was going on but couldn't find where the header is supposed to be added. `cs-import-documents` just calls `cs-cmd` with "CSImportDocuments" as an arg, which is a class in CloudSearchTools-1.0.jar (in /lib of where ever you installed the tools). You could try poking around in there or posting on the AWS support forum.

Comment: @kamalpreet - Did you get this working? I am having the same issue with very similar cs-import command, Im getting the same error when i reference s3:// as the source. I guess i need to provide additional parameters for authorization but no idea what they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you are using different version of java. 
Please try to degrade java version. hope it will work. i had similar kind of issue before after degrading it to lower version fixed my problem.